# diagonal lines as background for css - how to switch angle

Tags: css

http://jsbin.com/enazac/1/

How do I change the direction so that instead of the lines going in "\" direction, they can go in "/" direction?  I found this css online and I love it, just need to switch directions.

Warning: I trimmed the css down quite a bit so that it works definitely in Chrome, I'm not sure if other browsers will render it.  Thanks.

Css:

```
.diagonal_lines_pattern {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0, #E76801), color-stop(0.25, #E76801), color-stop(0.25, #EC7F24), color-stop(0.5, #EC7F24), color-stop(0.5, #E76801), color-stop(0.75, #E76801), color-stop(0.75, #EC7F24));
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play around with the CSS... Change lefts to rights, tops to bottoms...

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom,...
```

More info on [`-webkit-gradient`](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safaricssref/articles/Functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
.diagonal_lines_pattern{
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #E76801), color-stop(0.25, #E76801), color-stop(0.25, #EC7F24), color-stop(0.5, #EC7F24), color-stop(0.5, #E76801), color-stop(0.75, #E76801), color-stop(0.75, #EC7F24));
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not render anything in Firefox (CSS appears to be incorrect).